# How do I print the result of the user input?

Tags: c

the ; before void was expected by the compiler. 
my real question is :
I was able to enter the ID and the name but I can't see it in printf.
Was it because my data was not recorded in the pointer? 
How to fix the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct data 
{
 int* ID;
 char* Name;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data data1;
    struct data *data1Ptr;
    data1Ptr = &data1;
    printf("New ID:\n");
    scanf("%d",data1.ID);
    printf("Name:\n");
    scanf("%s",data1.Name);
    printf("The new ID is \n",&data1.ID);
    printf("The name input is \n",&data1.Name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited your code to make a bit more sense, you sound confused about the semicolon which simply terminates the declaration of `struct data`.

Comment: you use `%d` and `%s` in scanf to read a integer and a string, you have to use those format modifiers in the printf as well

Comment: `struct data` need the entity for that member of pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `printf()` correctly.

It doesn't magically handle formatting any arguments: you must *tell it* what arguments you're sending, and where you want their values to go, using format specifiers (starting with `%`).

You need:

```
printf("The new ID is %d\n", data1.ID);
printf("The name input is '%s'\n", data1.Name);
```

Also note that `ID` shouldn't be `int *`, it needs to store an actual integer so it should be `int` only.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc and free */

struct data 
{
    /*int* ID; why a pointer? */
    int ID;
    char *Name;
};

/* void main() Noooo */
int main(void)
{
    struct data data1;
    struct data *data1Ptr; /* unused */

    data1Ptr = &data1;
    printf("New ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &data1.ID); /* scanf expects a pointer */
    printf("Name:\n");
    /* you have to reserve mem for name before */
    data1.Name = malloc(100);
    /* check result of malloc here */
    scanf("%s",data1.Name);
    /*printf("The new ID is \n",data1.ID); You forget %d */
    printf("The new ID is %d\n",data1.ID);
    /* printf("The name input is \n",data1.Name); You forget %s */
    printf("The name input is %s\n",data1.Name);
    free(data1.Name);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: If you declare Name as `char Name[100]` inside `struct data` there is no need to `malloc`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a number of issues here. First you chose to make `Name` and `ID` pointers in your struct. That means you need to dynamically allocate memory to both before you start using them:

```
struct data data1;
data1.ID = malloc(sizeof(int));
data1.Name = malloc(50); // so arbitrary amount big enough for a name.
```

I'm not sure why you chose to make `ID` a pointer, it doesn't have to be in this example and it would probably be easier to understand if it wasn't; so consider changing that.

Now [`scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) takes a format string, and a number of pointers to each type being read. In your case you're just reading an int and a string, so what you have:

```
scanf("%d",data1.ID);
scanf("%s",data1.Name);
```

is fine, keep in mind if you choose to change `ID` to a `int` instead of a pointer you'll need to pass the address of it: `scanf("%s",&data1.ID);`

[`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) takes a format string, and the data in the format to be printed. In you case:

```
printf("The new ID is \n",&data1.ID);  // you're giving the address of the int
printf("The name input is \n",&data1.Name); // and the address of the string
```

but you didn't provide any format... and you don't want to send the address of your pointers, that doesn't make sense.

```
printf("The new ID is %d\n",*data1.ID);  // %d for an int, and * to dereference
printf("The name input is %s\n",data1.Name); // %s for a string
```

What you wanted to do was use `%d` and `%s` for the int and string accordingly (just like with `scanf()`) but then since `ID` is a pointer, you need to dereference it before passing it to `printf()`. There is no "string" type in C, so when you tell `printf()` to expect a string, it just wants a `char *` which is what `data1.Name` already is.